# How to automate interaction with Windows file explorer using Robot Framework?

Tags: windows, testing, selenium, selenium-rc, robotframework

I am writing robot tests for web testing using Google's Robot Framework with SeleniumLibrary (a test library) , one of my test involves uploading a file from the desktop by clicking on a"Browse" button on the webpage and using the windows file explorer window that pops up to navigate to and select the file ( providing a text path to file is disabled on the website for security reasons.) 
I have tried digging around but found little on automating this Windows File Explorer action , is there a way I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Autoit](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/) library. It might let you do what you want.